# Triangular inequality for variances

Tags: inequality, random-variables, variance, triangle-inequality

is it possible to prove that Var[a] ≤ Var[b], knowing that a=b-c, where a, b, c are three dependent random variables?
I tried using the triangular inequality, but I have just obtained: |b-c| ≤ a ≤ b+c

Comment: What is Var(a+c) in terms of Var(a) and Var(c)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I tried to simplify... To make a long story short:  

Let $x(n)$ be an estimator of $\mu$ (asymptotically consistent and unbiased): $E[x(n)]=\mu$.  
Let $e(n) = x(n)-\mu$ the estimation error.  
Let $f(n) = x(n)-x(N)$. I obtain that $f(n) = x(n) - \mu +\mu - x(N) = e(n)-e(N)$.  

I can see by data that $Var[f(n)] \leq Var[e(n)], \forall n$. But I would like to prove it analytically.  
Thank you for your precious help.